# How do i turn my character into a ragdoll during an animation

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, bones, physics

Hey im kinda new to blender, id like to know if its possible to turn my character into a ragdoll in the middle of an animation or something like that. My idea is like my character tries to do a backflip but horribly fails, breaking his neck and then turning into a ragdoll. Heres an example of what i want:

[image]

And then make him turn into a ragdoll

Comment: you'll probably need to use connected rigid body as explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUmIKWVrHZU